# run a VBA scipt if write a new e-mail

Tags: email, vba, outlook, exchange-server

I wrote an VBA:

```
Sub ToChange()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNachrich As MailItem 

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set objNachrich = olApp.CreateItem(0)
Set Mail = objNachrich

Mail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Info"
Mail.Display
End Sub
```

It changes the "from"-attribute to "Info" and works fine if I start it.

But, I want to run it automaticly if I open a window to write a new e-mail. Is there a posibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

you can add a new button on the menu-bar ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding it properly, you can just call this procedure on the Load event of a form.